# How would one prove $[f,[\nabla^2,f]]=-2(\nabla f)^2$?

Tags: notation, derivatives

How would one prove this equation:

$$[f,[\nabla^2,f]]=-2(\nabla f)^2 $$

---

And I'm confused that $\nabla f\nabla f$ equals $(\nabla f)^2$ or $\nabla(f\nabla f)$.

Comment: Maybe maths SE is a better home for this question. Also, please show what you have done. It is pretty straightforward: all you need to do is assume $\nabla$ fulfills the Leibnitz rule (so the relationship works for *any* covariant as well as co-ordinate derivative - this is really the definition of $\nabla$) and also take heed that $-2(\nabla f)^2$ is to be interpreted as a multiplication operator.  $\nabla f \nabla f$ is, strictly speaking, ambiguous without brackets: it could be either of your expressions.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451 . More generally, $[[\nabla^2,f],g]h=2(\nabla f)\cdot(\nabla g)h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1

$[\nabla^2,f]g=\nabla \cdot \nabla(fg)-f\nabla^2g=\nabla \cdot ((\nabla f)g+f(\nabla g))-f\nabla^2 g=(\nabla^2 f)g+2(\nabla f)\cdot(\nabla g)+f\nabla^2 g-f\nabla^2g=(\nabla^2f)g+2(\nabla f)\cdot(\nabla g)$

$\Rightarrow [\nabla^2,f]=(\nabla^2 f)+2(\nabla f)\cdot \nabla$

Step 2

\begin{eqnarray*}
[f,[\nabla^2,f]]g & = & [f,(\nabla^2 f)+2(\nabla f) \cdot \nabla]g \\
& = & [f,2(\nabla f) \cdot \nabla]g \\
& = & 2(\nabla f) \cdot [f,\nabla]g \\
& = & 2(\nabla f) \cdot (f\nabla g-\nabla(fg)) \\
& = & 2(\nabla f) \cdot (-(\nabla f)g)
\end{eqnarray*}

$\Rightarrow$

$[f,[\nabla^2,f]]=-2(\nabla f) \cdot (\nabla f)=-2(\nabla f)^2$

Pls correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

Comment: $[f,(\nabla^2f)+2(\nabla f)\cdot\nabla]g=[f,2(\nabla f)\cdot\nabla]g$ why?

Comment: $[f,(\nabla^2 f)]=0$

Comment: Fine,I know that.

Comment: $[\nabla,f]=\nabla{f}$,so $[\nabla^2,f]=\nabla\cdot[\nabla,f]+[\nabla,f]\cdot\nabla=\nabla^2f+(\nabla{f}) \cdot \nabla $ , what's wrong?

Comment: $\nabla \cdot [\nabla,f]\not=\nabla^2 f$, because the 1st $\nabla$ operates not only on $[\nabla,f]$.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward if you assume $\nabla$ fulfills the Leibnitz rule (so the relationship works for any covariant as well as co-ordinate derivative - this is really the definition of $\nabla$) and also take heed that $−2(\nabla f)^2$  is to be interpreted as a multiplication operator. $\nabla f \nabla f$  is, strictly speaking, ambiguous without brackets: it could be either of your expressions.

Comment: e.g. $[a,\nabla{b}]=a\nabla{b}-\nabla{b}a$,So what about the $\nabla{b}a$ equals $\nabla(ba)$ or $(\nabla b)a$ ?

Comment: In an expression like $[a,\nabla b]$ you are to read $\nabla b$ as a multiplication operator - it doesn't really  make sense otherwise. Hence $[a,\nabla b] = a \nabla b - (\nabla b) a$

Comment: $[\nabla,a]b=\nabla{a}b-a\nabla{b}$ what about this $\nabla{a}b$? In my book there is $[\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}},x]f(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(xf(x))-x \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}f(x)$ what's difference?

Comment: In that case, each component of the simple gradient works exactly like the identity in your book. It may be helpful to write out the mappings fully: firstly, I am assuming that $\nabla$ is simply the gradient operator (although, because all you need is the Leibnitz rule, it can be broader than than). Now, look at the image of $g(x,y,z)$ under your Lie bracket: we have $g\mapsto [f,[\nabla^2,f]]g = f (\nabla^2(f\, g) - f \nabla^2\, g) - (\nabla^2 (f^2\, g) - f \nabla^2(f\,g))$. In the simple vector calculus interpretation with $\nabla^2h=\nabla\cdot(\nabla h)$ you can now expand.